# HTML KEBAB FOR MULTIPLE INSTANCES

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a kebab menu for a page that displays multiple blogs. However, my code only triggers the kebab for only the first post and doesn't work for others. I included the HTML, CSS, and javascript for clarity. Only the first post works (in terms of the kebab menu). Please help.

```js
var kebab = document.querySelector('.kebab'),
  middle = document.querySelector('.middle'),
  cross = document.querySelector('.cross'),
  dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

kebab.addEventListener('click', function() {
  middle.classList.toggle('active');
  cross.classList.toggle('active');
  dropdown.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
.kebab {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 16px;
  top: 12px;
}

.kebab figure {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #00bcd4;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.middle {
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.72, 1.2, 0.71, 0.72);
  transform: scale(1);
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1px 0.1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1px 0.3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.1px);
  filter: blur(0.1px);
}

.middle.active {
  transform: scale(4.5);
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.32, 2.04, 0.85, 0.54);
  box-shadow: 0 0.1px 0.1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1px 0.3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cross {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.72, 1.2, 0.71, 0.72);
  font-size: 22px;
  user-select: none;
}

.cross.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.32, 2.04, 0.85, 0.54);
}

h1,
a,
li {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  background: #00bcd4;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 20%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

a,
li {
  color: #6b6b6b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav>li:hover {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3em;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.dropdown li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown li a:hover {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.dropdown:hover ul {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.dropdown.active {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.5, 1.8, 0.9, 0.8);
}

.follow {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #03A9F4;
  display: block;
  margin: 300px auto 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.follow i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: margin-right 0.2s ease;
}

.follow:hover {
  width: 134px;
}

.follow:hover i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .follow {
    margin: 400px auto 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="kebab">
  <figure></figure>
  <figure class="middle"></figure>
  <p class="cross">x</p>
  <figure></figure>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Coding</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Web Development</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please ensure the code you've provided here represents a [mre]. If the CSS is important to demonstrating the issue you're attempting to describe, should absolutely be including it. See also: [ask]

Comment: @esqew, it's updated now with CSS code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "my code only triggers the kebab for only the first post and doesn't work for others." What represents your posts and specifically what represents the first post.  Is your example fully illustrating the problem?

Comment: @ Jon P, Okay, I'm trying to put together a page that shows posts from DB by multiple users. Each post has a kebab button that triggers a menu. The current code only works for the first post returned from the DB but doesn't work for others, when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only selects one element. I'm assuming you have multiple elements with class `kebab`. I've added an event listener to each of these in a `forEachLoop`, getting the elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Your code only adds the event listener to the first *kebab*.

I've also simplified the js by just adding the `active` class the the parent element, adjusting the CSS to accommodate this.

```js
var kebab = document.querySelectorAll('.kebab');
kebab.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(this)
  this.classList.toggle("active");
}));
```

```css
.kebab {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 16px;
  top: 12px;
}

.kebab figure {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #00bcd4;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.middle {
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.72, 1.2, 0.71, 0.72);
  transform: scale(1);
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1px 0.1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1px 0.3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.1px);
  filter: blur(0.1px);
}

.active .middle{
  transform: scale(4.5);
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.32, 2.04, 0.85, 0.54);
  box-shadow: 0 0.1px 0.1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1px 0.3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cross {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.72, 1.2, 0.71, 0.72);
  font-size: 22px;
  user-select: none;
}

.active .cross {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.32, 2.04, 0.85, 0.54);
}

h1,
a,
li {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  background: #00bcd4;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 20%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

a,
li {
  color: #6b6b6b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav>li:hover {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3em;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.dropdown li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown li a:hover {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.dropdown:hover ul {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.active .dropdown{
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.5, 1.8, 0.9, 0.8);
}

.follow {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #03A9F4;
  display: block;
  margin: 300px auto 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.follow i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: margin-right 0.2s ease;
}

.follow:hover {
  width: 134px;
}

.follow:hover i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .follow {
    margin: 400px auto 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="kebab">
  <figure></figure>
  <figure class="middle"></figure>
  <p class="cross">x</p>
  <figure></figure>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Coding</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Web Development</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kebab">
  <figure></figure>
  <figure class="middle"></figure>
  <p class="cross">x</p>
  <figure></figure>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Coding</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Web Development</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kebab">
  <figure></figure>
  <figure class="middle"></figure>
  <p class="cross">x</p>
  <figure></figure>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Coding</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Web Development</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I applied your code, but it's alternating. It works for the first, but doesn't work for the second...and so forth

Comment: You need to provide a more representative example of your code then. Make sure what you provide in the question is fully representative of the problem. As it stands that is not the case.

Comment: @Philly To elaborate on my previous comment, you don't need to provide "everything", just enough to demonstrate the problem. If it is alternating, provide an example with 4 kebab elements that demonstrates this behavior. For more info see : [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var kebab = document.querySelector('.kebab'),
  middle = document.querySelector('.middle'),
  cross = document.querySelector('.cross'),
  dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

kebab.addEventListener('click', function() {
  middle.classList.toggle('active');
  cross.classList.toggle('active');
  dropdown.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
.kebab {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 16px;
  top: 12px;
}

.kebab figure {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #00bcd4;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.middle {
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.72, 1.2, 0.71, 0.72);
  transform: scale(1);
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1px 0.1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1px 0.3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.1px);
  filter: blur(0.1px);
}

.middle.active {
  transform: scale(4.5);
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.32, 2.04, 0.85, 0.54);
  box-shadow: 0 0.1px 0.1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0.1px 0.3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cross {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.72, 1.2, 0.71, 0.72);
  font-size: 22px;
  user-select: none;
}

.cross.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.32, 2.04, 0.85, 0.54);
}

h1,
a,
li {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  background: #00bcd4;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 20%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

a,
li {
  color: #6b6b6b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav>li:hover {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 3em;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.dropdown li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown li a:hover {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.dropdown:hover ul {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.dropdown.active {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.5, 1.8, 0.9, 0.8);
}

.follow {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #03A9F4;
  display: block;
  margin: 300px auto 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.follow i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: margin-right 0.2s ease;
}

.follow:hover {
  width: 134px;
}

.follow:hover i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .follow {
    margin: 400px auto 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="kebab">
  <figure></figure>
  <figure class="middle"></figure>
  <p class="cross">x</p>
  <figure></figure>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Coding</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.g.com">Web Development</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For CSS in `.dropdown` I had to change `right: 0;` to `left 10%`, or else it wouldn’t show at all. After that change, I can’t see anything that doesn’t work. It pops down and displays everything in the `<ul class="dropdown">` tag. However, I did notice that inside `<ul class="dropdown">` all the lists links have the same hrefs. Furthermore, the hrefs don’t lead anywhere (which I suspect was intentional).